# Best way to write Java 8 map statement that returns constant value

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, option-type

I have the following statement. The map always returned "Closed". But I think this statement `s -> "CLOSED"` could be rewritten using a better style.

Is there any better way to represent this?

```
String status = myOptional.map(s -> "CLOSED").orElse("OPEN");
```

Comment: Why do you need the optional `myOptional`?

Comment: think about `x -> "CLOSED"` for a minute - you don't use `x`, at all. so do you need `Optional` to begin with?

Comment: I like what you already have. I think I understand your question, but I also think that any attempt to modify will be just complication.

Comment: @Eugene OP doesn't need `x` in this use case, that doesn't means that the optional is not useful at some other place... @ZZZ Now you can't *simplify* that writing and stay in the functional style, afterall, `x` is needed because you need to be clear that you don't want to use it :-)

Comment: I totally disagree with the closing "primarily opinion based", OP just want to know if a shorter form exists.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès right, my point was that this is an indication that it _might_ be un-needed, should have made that a lot more explicit. thx for the comment

Answer (score 3):

Just use a ternary operatory to check for its presence :

```
String status = myOptional.isPresent() ? "CLOSED" : "OPEN";
```

Comment: Yes. This is good. But I want to know if there is a better way to change s->"CLOSED".

Comment: @ZZZ well since you're not using the `Optional` value, there is no need of the `map` operation there.